# CMake can't find source dir when run from bash script in WSL

Tags: bash, scripts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cmake

I'm running the Ubuntu version of Windows Subsystem for Linux. 
In there I've set up a simple cmake project and created a script to save me from typing out

`cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../../`

every time I want to build. My CMakeLists.txt exists in two directories above (thus `../../`). The build works fine if I type the command above manually OR run a powershell script with the **exact** same command and nothing else.

But running this bash script inside WSL

```
#!/bin/bash
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../../
```

I receive the error `" does not exist.source directory "/mnt/c/dev-files/C/Practice/`.

It looks like the bash script messes up the error output of cmake, so I'm guessing the script is executing cmake or passing the arguments incorrectly but I have no idea why.

Comment: Did you create the script using a Windows editor? does it have DOS-style (CRLF) line endings by any chance?

Comment: @steeldriver I did edit the script a few times with vscode while executing it through the vscode terminal.

Comment: How exactly do you execute the script? Where it is located?

Comment: @pa4080 The script is located in "/mnt/c/dev-files/C/Practice/debug/linux" and it can only be executed in that directory. No sym links or and not available through PATH.

Comment: Probably, as workaround, you can try to `cd ../../` first and then execute the `cmeake` command with the current directory as argument.

Comment: @pa4080 That could work but the issue was something completely different, thank you anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying out other commands i noticed that some the other command arguments had the `\r` in line endings pointed out by errors.

The issue was that the script had windows line endings, as steeldriver commented in the question.

It was en easy fix with the `dos2unix` command,
ex:

`dos2unix script.sh`